# Extracting text from a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I want to import data from Excel into an existing table in a SQL Server database.

I have a column like `Gender` and the values are `Male` and `Female` in Excel. I want to insert only the first character into database, like `M` and `F`.

How should I achieve this thing in SSIS for SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Derived Column transformation. Add an expression that converts the gender column into the initial. You can use something like `SUBSTRING(GENDER,1,1)` for this.